# Issue installing mitmproxy using pip on Amazon EC2 instance (CentOS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, pip, mitmproxy, libffi

I am trying to install mitproxy on my EC2 linux instance using pip:

`sudo pip install mitmproxy`

I have python2.7 installed, and now 2 instances of libffi

`$ rpm -qa | grep libff
libffi-3.0.13-11.4.amzn1.x86_64
libffi-devel-3.0.13-11.4.amzn1.x86_64`

but each time I try to run the install command I get the following error message:

`gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:423:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
     #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
                                  ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Any thoughts where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is still an issue

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem with following solution:

1. wget source code gzip package from https://www.openssl.org/source/
2. config&&make&&make install

Good luck!